# Do you have to stub methods in Rspec Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I had a class called listing and product:

```
class Listing
  belongs_to :product

  def item
    @item ||= Product.find(product_id)
  end

  def url
   "http://example.com/#{@item.pid}"
  end

end


class Product
  has_one :listing
  attr_accessor :pid #returns an integer
end
```

in my spec file I create a listing object with factory girl and assign it a product. I tested it in previous specs and whenever I called:

```
@listing.item.id.should eq(@product.id)
```

It would pass.

However, I tried to call:

```
@product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
@listing = FactoryGirl.create(:listing)

@product.listing = @listing
@listing.url.should eq("...")
```

And **it could not call the url method on the listing class**... How could I get this to pass *but still make for a good test?*

Comment: what's the actual error message you got? (ie, what do you mean when you say "it could not call the url method")

Comment: undefined method error

Comment: Ah, perhaps I wasn't clear enough. Can you give us the actual text of the error and the backtrace please.

Comment: do you really need `attr_accessor`, and not `attr_accessible`? If the field `pid` is stored in the DB. you have to use the second keyword. And show us the factory models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Listing` model, the instance variable `@item` only gets defined if the `item` method is called, which doesn't happen in your test. As a result, when the `url` method is called, `@item` is nil and `@item.pid` results in an `undefined method error` as a result of sending `pid` to `nil`.

You can, however, change your `@item.pid` reference in the `url` method to be simply `item.pid` and you'll be ok, as this will invoke the `item` method.

While that explains the error you're getting, I can't really advise you on what a good test is because it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish in your application.

Comment: Wouldn't the item method get called when the url method is called? and the ||= operator should set the value of item since it has not been set yet. I am basically trying to cache an object with the item method. It did not seem to work. :(

Comment: No, the `item` method is not invoked in the body of the `url` method. Only the `@item` instance variable is referenced. I'll update my answer to indicate what you can do about this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why you created the `item` method when you already have the `belongs_to` association set up.

```
class Listing
  belongs_to :product

  def url
   "http://example.com/#{product.pid}"
  end
end

class Product
  has_one :listing
  attr_accessible :pid
end

# test setup
# you can define the association in the factory
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :listing do
    association :product
  end

  factory :product do
    pid 1234
  end
end

# test
listing = FactoryGirl.create(:listing)
listing.url.should eq "http://example.com/1234"
```